# Fetching the complete contents of a UIWebView including !doctype and html tags

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I've been exploring `[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.all[0].outerHTML"]` but this leaves the !doctype tag.

I'm trying to avoid `stringWithContentsOfURL:` as it makes a new call.

Is there any way I can fetch the complete source of a UIWebView including !doctype and html tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the Doctype and the rest of the HTML code in one method call. However you can build the Doctype with Javascript like this (credit to [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) for this Javascript solution):

```
var node = document.doctype;
var html = "<!DOCTYPE "
         + node.name
         + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '')
         + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') 
         + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '')
         + '>';
```

So put this Javascript Code into an NSString and call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` with it. That should give you the !Doctype. Then you can add the rest of the HTML as you described in your question.

However I'd like to suggest a second approach: Load the contents of the URL into an NSString first by using `stringWithContentsOfURL:` and then load the NSString into the UIWebView using `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`

With that approach you get the real full HTML as a string (including the actual !Doctype and html tags) and you only use 1 request. Just make sure that you use the correct baseURL so that CSS and JS files and referenced images are loaded correctly.

Comment: thanks!!  I'll use the second approach of loading the contents of the URL into an NSString first and then loading the UIWebView. Are you aware of any disadvantages of using this approach?

Comment: I am using this approach too and I have not found any disadvantage yet.